# How do I use matlab on two computers and load files (located in different file locations) in my script?

Tags: matlab

I plan to use matlab at school's computer lab.  At home, I'll use Matlab on my own computer.  I use dropbox to store and access my files from different computers.  Sometimes I need to load a file into my matlab script.  My problem is:  if I use both the school's and my own computer, my files will be in two different file locations; I will need to change the matlab code each time I work at school and at home.  What can I do?

Thanks.

PS I could bring my laptop to school and do all my matlab assignments on my laptop. I'd rather not, because my laptop is heavy and might get stolen or damaged during my science labs.

Comment: If you store both your m-file and data file in your dropbox, there should be no problem. Can you give more information?

Comment: You can use git or other version control system and make private remote repository. With this its very easy to sync source files in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the full path in your matlab code when loading a file, you can use `pwd` to get the full path of the m-file `test.m` you currently work on. Example:

Your code:

```
load('c:\matlab\myfile\test.mat')
```

Revised code:

```
load([pwd,'\test.mat'])
```

I've supposed that the files `test.mat` and `test.m` are both in the same folder `myfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I use 3 computers

1. Office computer
2. House Desktop
3. Laptop

I came up with a solution for Google Drive (the same can be applied for Box). I created a function called gpath (short for Google Drive path). The function checks to see which computer I am on and then changes the path name accordingly. Here is the function

```
function [] = gpath(A)

[~,pcname] = system('hostname'); %fetch the pc's current name
pcname=pcname(1:end-1)
pcname = cellstr(pcname); %turn it into a string
homeDesktop = {'Patricks-PC'}; %This is the name of my pc at home make sure its not the same as my desktop...it might be
z640 = {'M-2UA638373V'};
laptop = {'DESKTOP-4QHJ1G7'};

if strcmp(pcname,z640) ==1 %for z640
    path = strcat('C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\', A)
    cd(path)

elseif strcmp(pcname,homeDesktop) ==1 %for Antec p193
    path = strcat('H:\Google Drive\', A)
    cd(path)

elseif strcmp(pcname,laptop) ==1 %for ASUS laptop
    path = strcat('C:\Users\Patty\Google Drive', A)
    cd(path)

end
```

Now lets say for example I want to set my directory to Google Drive\Project1 instead of writing

```
cd('C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\Project1')
```

I simply write

```
gpath('Project1')
```

and this code will work on all 3 of my computers and means I don't need to change my script everytime I switch from working at the office to at home. If you like this answer consider giving me a thumbs up.